# Logical OR in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I have a table which contained the following dimensions :

```
mkt_id, dow, dvc, feat, val
```

val is of type text and contains true/false.
(mkt_id, dow, dvc, feat) forms a key and val represents a value.

To select the various key - value pairs, I used the query :

```
SELECT * from <tablename> where mkt_id in (...) and feat = 'xyz'
```

**NEXT** : Another dimension was added tot he table called `ptd`.

For for the same combination of key (mkt_id, doq, dvc, feat) I got multiple values of `val` due to the added dimension `ptd`.

Now my requirement is that I have to output the value as True if any of the value for a particular key (mkt_id, doq, dvc, feat) is true otherwise false.

**My attempt at the solution** :

```
SELECT mkt_id, dow, dvc, feat, 
CASE WHEN trueCount >= 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as val 
FROM( SELECT DISTINCT mkt_id,dow,dvc,feat,
SUM( CASE WHEN val='true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS trueCount 
FROM <tablename> WHERE mkt_id in (...) and feat = 'xyz'
```

The problem is that this query take a lot of time to execute and ultimately errors out due to `database or disk full`.

Any help in optimizing the query or another approach to the solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To get one output row for each `mkt_id`/`dow`/`dvc`/`feat` combination, use GROUP BY on those columns.

When comparing strings, `true` is larger than `false`, so you can use MAX() to select it:

```
SELECT mkt_id, dow, dvc, feat, MAX(val) AS val
FROM MyTableNameIsTopSecret
WHERE ...
GROUP BY mkt_id, dow, dvc, feat
```

(The GROUP BY can be optimized with a single index on these four columns; the columns used in the WHERE should come first in the index.)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid `GROUP BY`? Group by increases the cost of the query and I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Whatever the query, it must *somehow* search for and merge rows with matching `mkt_id`/`dow`/`dvc`/`feat` values. With GROUP BY, optimization is at least *possible*.